# Javascript loses reference to AIR function

Tags: javascript, html, air, window

I have an Adobe Air desktop application which has, as part of the app, an HTML window for displaying HTML/JavaScript. During initial load, I am able to successfully call from JavaScript back to the enclosing AIR application. If, however, I press an AIR button to reload the exact same content into the HTML window, the JavaScript call fails. The JavaScript code is automatically generated and inserted into the HTML and looks like this:

```
<button onclick="bClk0a()">Connect
<script>
function bClk0a()
 { window.bdPaneInstance.getAccelData("Name","https://... "); }
</script>
</button>
```

On initial invocation, the "window.bdPaneInstance" is correctly associated with the public function "getAccelData". However, once an AIR Button in the enclosing window is pressed (which simply reloads the exact same text), window.bdPaneInstance is permanently null. I infer that the process associated with 'event listener', which is how the AIR Button reloads the AIR HTML window, somehow changes the window associated with the HTML so that "bdPaneInstance" is no longer visible. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Some Additional Information. Development is being done on Windows V7 64Bit with Flash Builder 4.6.  window.bdPaneInstance is initialized via this code: `    persistThis.bdLoader = persistThis.searchPane.detailPane.bdBody.htmlLoader;` `    persistThis.bdLoader.window.bdPaneInstance = persistThis;`

Comment: Some Additional Information. Development is being done on Windows V7 64Bit with Flash Builder 4.6.  window.bdPaneInstance is initialized via this code: `    persistThis.bdLoader = persistThis.searchPane.detailPane.bdBody.htmlLoader;` `    persistThis.bdLoader.window.bdPaneInstance = persistThis;` where "persistThis" is set equal to "this" when the enclosing class is first created. Perhaps not necessary, but trying to maintain "this" across callbacks.  window.bdPaneInstance is set ONCE and not touched  afterwards. bdBody is an AIR HTML object. bdPaneInstance and persistThis are both class vars.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the root cause of the issue is that adding an eventListener for Event.COMPLETE which only executes a single line setting the vertical scroll position of the HTML object causes the htmlLoader to lose previously set references. So the fix is to add an additional event listener which executes after the vertical scroll position is set to (re)establish the window.bdPaneInstance variable.